# JSON or XML? Which is better?

Tags: json, xml

Which format is better to save and access data for a web application?

Is JSON more flexible or should XML be used?

Comment: CSV is the best format

Comment: Hammer or screwdriver? Which is better?

Comment: They generally have the same flexibility for saving object trees unless you use very specific format features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Choose XML if**

- An industry standard XSD exists.
- You value more mature validation standard and tools.
- You need to transform the data to another XML form.  (XSLT is excellent for transformations.)
- Or, you have to represent mixed content (tags mixed within text).

**Choose JSON if**

- The closer fit to JavaScript is valuable to you or your callers.
- You prefer a lighter-weight solution.
- Or, the above **Choose XML if** reasons do not apply to you.

Comment: "more mature validation standards" @kjhughes - thanks for that information.